# page redirect issue codeigniter : 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I'm creating an application using CodeIgniter.

When I enter the correct email and password I should be redirected to dashboard but I get this redirection:/auth/login and it shows 
[image]

I may clarify that I allowed mod_rewrite , added the write base_url and allowed connection on apache

My Config.php

```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/stock-v2/';
```

My controller :

```
 public function login()
{

    $this->logged_in();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        // true case
        $email_exists = $this->model_auth->check_email($this->input->post('email'));

        if($email_exists == TRUE) {
            $login = $this->model_auth->login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'));

            if($login) {

                $logged_in_sess = array(
                    'id' => $login['id'],
                    'username'  => $login['username'],
                    'email'     => $login['email'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($logged_in_sess);
                redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
            }
            else {
                $this->data['errors'] = 'Incorrect username/password combination';
                $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->data['errors'] = 'Email does not exists';

            $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
        }   
    }
    else {
        // false case
        $this->load->view('login');
    }   
}

    */
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have index function in controller named Dashboard.php?

Comment: yes I do have a index

Comment: the error says `page you requested is missing`, where is your dashboard controller code?

Comment: I have a folder called controller and the dashboard controller is situated there, also auth is the authentification controller and login is just a function so when I press sign in it must redirect me to dashboard instead of auth\login (that I mentioned as a default controller of the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your .htaccess file. Paste this in .htaccess in your app directory (in same level to applications) and will works :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in conf.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].'/stock-v2/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Then use regirect like this without refresh:

```
redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
```

Check in http.conf do you allow override for your domain?

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: replace your content in .htaccess with this and will work!

Comment: I replaced it but no chance ! :/

Comment: should i change this one with allow in place of deny                             
           `<IfModule authz_core_module>
 Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
 Deny from all
</IfModule>`

Comment: I made changes again. Try it. What is your full url when redirect to dashboard?

Comment: here's the full URL when i redirect : http://127.0.0.1:8000/stock-v2/auth/login and auth is the defaut controller

Comment: in http.conf make sure u enable overdire for your domein:  AllowOverride All. See my changed answer.

Comment: I've already set it when I first started working but my problem persists

Answer (score 0):

You must configure your base URL. 
If you're work on the local server then try this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/stock-v2/';
```

Otherwise (live)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://<put your domain here>';
```